# Filtering WFS request by bbox, typeName and typeID

Tags: wfs, filter

I never worked with WFS before but am forced to get a few responses from a public WFS server for a prototype research project. I have skimmed many resources and tried out lots of combinations but I got too frustrated now to continue trying to solve it on my own.

Currently with this request :
https://nfs.kystverket.no/arcgis/services/nfs/NFSSistOperativ/MapServer/WFSServer?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=2.0.0&typeName=nfs_NFSSistOperativ:Fastsj%C3%B8merke&bbox=60.417901,5.135830,60.430572,5.167121

I successfully limit the retrieved entries to only the ones within the boundingbox and to the ones of type "nfs_NFSSistOpreativ:Fastsj%C3%B8merke":

```
<wfs:FeatureCollection timeStamp="2023-11-18T17:47:53Z" numberMatched="3" numberReturned="3" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2 http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd https://nfs.kystverket.no/arcgis/services/nfs/NFSSistOperativ/MapServer/WFSServer https://nfs.kystverket.no/arcgis/services/nfs/NFSSistOperativ/MapServer/WFSServer?service=wfs%26version=2.0.0%26request=DescribeFeatureType">
<wfs:member>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:Fastsjømerke gml:id="Fastsjømerke.1210">
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:OBJECTID>1210</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:OBJECTID>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:SHAPE>
<gml:Point gml:id="Fastsjømerke.1210.pn.0" srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25833">
<gml:pos>-40820.56620000 6739290.21920000</gml:pos>
</gml:Point>
</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:SHAPE>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:SjomerkeNr>18433M</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:SjomerkeNr>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:GISOBJID>39221</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:GISOBJID>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:Long>5.15278583</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:Long>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:Lat>60.42480527</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:Lat>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:navn/>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:sted>Hetlevik</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:sted>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:beliggenhet>Askøy</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:beliggenhet>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:Klasse>SG - Stang</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:Klasse>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:navigasjonsinstallasjonseier>Kystverket</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:navigasjonsinstallasjonseier>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:Status>Operativ</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:Status>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:kystverkRegion>Kystverket Vest</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:kystverkRegion>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:Refleksfarge>Grønn</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:Refleksfarge>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:toppmerkeType>Viser</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:toppmerkeType>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:merkeform>Stang,påle</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:merkeform>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:merketype>Foul ground mark(y Yachting)</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:merketype>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:OppdatertDato>2022-02-25T13:20:39</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:OppdatertDato>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:OppdatertAv>10041</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:OppdatertAv>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:PACC>0.20700000</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:PACC>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:MaltDato>2008-02-14T12:41:46</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:MaltDato>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:MaltAv>9998</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:MaltAv>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:TYPEID>AndreFastmerker</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:TYPEID>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:NavID>223370</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:NavID>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:GlobalID>{E3F35709-B5B9-4A74-A3CF-B0923E6F7FC4}</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:GlobalID>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:S57Status>Permanent</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:S57Status>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:nautiskFunksjon>Brukbar</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:nautiskFunksjon>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:Kategori>Mindre viktig for sikker navigasjon</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:Kategori>
</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:Fastsjømerke>
</wfs:member>
<wfs:member>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:Fastsjømerke gml:id="Fastsjømerke.1226">
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:OBJECTID>1226</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:OBJECTID>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:SHAPE>
<gml:Point gml:id="Fastsjømerke.1226.pn.0" srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25833">
<gml:pos>-40831.61130000 6739286.39590000</gml:pos>
</gml:Point>
</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:SHAPE>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:SjomerkeNr>18432M</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:SjomerkeNr>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:GISOBJID>39220</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:GISOBJID>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:Long>5.15259852</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:Long>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:Lat>60.42475670</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:Lat>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:navn/>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:sted>Hetlevik</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:sted>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:beliggenhet>Askøy</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:beliggenhet>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:Klasse>SG - Stang</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:Klasse>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:navigasjonsinstallasjonseier>Kystverket</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:navigasjonsinstallasjonseier>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:Status>Operativ</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:Status>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:kystverkRegion>Kystverket Vest</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:kystverkRegion>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:Refleksfarge>Grønn</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:Refleksfarge>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:toppmerkeType>Viser</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:toppmerkeType>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:merkeform>Stang,påle</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:merkeform>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:merketype>Foul ground mark(y Yachting)</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:merketype>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:OppdatertDato>2022-02-25T13:19:16</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:OppdatertDato>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:OppdatertAv>10041</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:OppdatertAv>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:PACC>0.19500000</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:PACC>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:MaltDato>2008-02-14T12:40:48</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:MaltDato>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:MaltAv>9998</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:MaltAv>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:TYPEID>StyrbordLateralMerke</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:TYPEID>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:NavID>222795</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:NavID>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:GlobalID>{CFEAAE53-75B7-4ABD-8116-E6B7D35A5BD6}</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:GlobalID>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:S57Status>Permanent</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:S57Status>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:nautiskFunksjon>Brukbar</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:nautiskFunksjon>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:Kategori>Mindre viktig for sikker navigasjon</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:Kategori>
</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:Fastsjømerke>
</wfs:member>
<wfs:member>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:Fastsjømerke gml:id="Fastsjømerke.1227">
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:OBJECTID>1227</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:OBJECTID>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:SHAPE>
<gml:Point gml:id="Fastsjømerke.1227.pn.0" srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25833">
<gml:pos>-40799.03330000 6739226.02670000</gml:pos>
</gml:Point>
</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:SHAPE>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:SjomerkeNr>18435M</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:SjomerkeNr>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:GISOBJID>39219</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:GISOBJID>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:Long>5.15334454</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:Long>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:Lat>60.42426616</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:Lat>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:navn> </nfs_NFSSistOperativ:navn>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:sted>Hetlevik</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:sted>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:beliggenhet>Askøy</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:beliggenhet>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:Klasse>SG - Stang</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:Klasse>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:navigasjonsinstallasjonseier>Kystverket</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:navigasjonsinstallasjonseier>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:Status>Operativ</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:Status>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:kystverkRegion>Kystverket Vest</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:kystverkRegion>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:toppmerkeRetning>120.00000000</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:toppmerkeRetning>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:Refleksfarge>Rød</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:Refleksfarge>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:toppmerkeType>Viser</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:toppmerkeType>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:merkeform>Stang,påle</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:merkeform>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:merketype>Foul ground mark(y Yachting)</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:merketype>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:OppdatertDato>2022-02-25T13:22:04</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:OppdatertDato>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:OppdatertAv>10041</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:OppdatertAv>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:PACC>0.24300000</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:PACC>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:MaltDato>2008-02-14T12:39:15</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:MaltDato>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:MaltAv>9999</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:MaltAv>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:TYPEID>BabordLateralMerke</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:TYPEID>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:NavID>222797</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:NavID>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:GlobalID>{EC5F3D5A-B948-4487-A096-6846F3AE77DB}</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:GlobalID>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:S57Status>Permanent</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:S57Status>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:nautiskFunksjon>God</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:nautiskFunksjon>
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:Kategori>Viktig for sikker navigasjon</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:Kategori>
</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:Fastsjømerke>
</wfs:member>
</wfs:FeatureCollection>
```

But I would like to only get entries where the typeID is "BabordLateralMerke".

```
<nfs_NFSSistOperativ:TYPEID>BabordLateralMerke</nfs_NFSSistOperativ:TYPEID>
```

I don't know what else to try, as after the filtering only one member should be retrieved for the given bbox...

This didn't work either: `https://nfs.kystverket.no/arcgis/services/nfs/NFSSistOperativ/MapServer/WFSServer?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=2.0.0&typename=nfs_NFSSistOperativ:Fastsjømerke&bbox=60.417901,5.135830,60.430572,5.167121&Filter=<ogc:Filter><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>TYPEID</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>BabordLateralMerke</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo></ogc:Filter>`

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use bbox or filter but not both. So, you need to roll the geometry filter into your filter with an and.

Comment: Thank you :) this helped me come up with a correct request.